# Cannot get file size after uploading using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, file

I need to validate one file field with required width,height and if file has not uploaded using JavaScript but its not happening like this. Here is my code:

```
<input type="file" name="copImage" id="copImage" class="form-control"  value="" onchange="setBackgroundImage(event);">
function setBackgroundImage(e){
     var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    bg = new Image();
    bg.src = url;
    bg.onload = function () {
        bgLoaded = true;
        backImageHeight=this.height;
        backImageWidth=this.width;
    };
    console.log('size bg',backImageHeight,backImageWidth);
  }
```

Here I could not get the file `height` and `width`. I also to check the if file has not uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pu the log statement inside the `onload` function. This is because you are trying to access the variable outside its scope, else define those variables outside onload function

```
bg.onload = function() {
    var bgLoaded = true,
    backImageHeight = this.height,
    backImageWidth = this.width;
    console.log('size bg',backImageHeight,backImageWidth);
  };
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/4k6hg0w3/1/)

> suppose i have one button and without selecting file if I am clicking
>   on the file alert should say to select the file.

Seems you cannot do that with `onchange` event handler because if file is not loaded. nothing has changed and so function wont fire. In that case you can create a variable & update its state on file upload. On clicking of the button check the variable state

```
var isFileLoaded = false;
function setBackgroundImage(fileValue) {
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(fileValue.files[0]);
  bg = new Image();
  if (fileValue.value !== '') {
    bg.src = url;
    bg.onload = function() {
      bgLoaded = true;
      isFileLoaded = true;
      backImageHeight = this.height;
      backImageWidth = this.width;
      console.log('size bg', backImageHeight, backImageWidth);
    };
  }
}

function buttonClick() {
  if (isFileLoaded) {

  } else {
    alert('No file selected')
  }

}
```

[**DEMO 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/4k6hg0w3/1/)

Comment: Thank you.its working. How to check the file has not selected yet.

Comment: could not get what you meant

Comment: suppose i have one button and without selecting file if I am clicking on the file alert should say to select the file.

Answer (score 0):

Hello You just need to log your height and width inside bg.onload function.these are outside of the scope of variables.thats why you not getting the height and width like this

```
function setBackgroundImage(e){
 var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
bg = new Image();
bg.src = url;
bg.onload = function () {
    bgLoaded = true;
    backImageHeight=this.height;
    backImageWidth=this.width;
        console.log('size bg',backImageHeight,backImageWidth);
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine in your code, you need to include console.log() within bg.onload block only like this .

```
function setBackgroundImage(e)
{
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    bg = new Image();
    bg.src = url;
    bg.onload = function () {
        bgLoaded = true;
        backImageHeight=this.height;
        backImageWidth=this.width;
        console.log('size bg',backImageHeight,backImageWidth);
    };

}

function isFileSelected()
{
    return document.getElementById('copImage').files.length > 0;
}
```

You can use **isFileSelected()** function to know whether file is selected or not .